# In T_SQL Null not allowed

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have two tables in Sybase
    Table1

```
ID   NAME   PRICE
123  KING   12.23
234  KONG   23.43

Table2  
ID  IND  CD
123 1    A

 When we do    "Desc Table2"

Column Name    Data Type   Null   Default Value
ID             Int         N          
IND            BIT         N           0
CD             CHAR        Y
```

So, table2 has a column that could never be null and has default value as 0. when I join both tables

```
select t1.*, t2.IND, t2.CD
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where  t1.ID *= t2.ID
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID   NAME   PRICE  IND  CD
123  KING   12.23  1    A
234  KONG   23.43  0
```

Desired output
I want to show null values for the fields those are not found in table2.
when I try to update to make it null than it give me message NULL not allowed.
It looks like Table2.IND field was setup initially as not null allowed.

OUTPUT:

```
ID   NAME   PRICE  IND  CD
123  KING   12.23  1    A
234  KONG   23.43
```

how to change this thing in my query so, I could see NULL if data not exist in table2.

Comment: You are implicitly using an inner join. switch to left outer join.

Comment: @Chet `*=` is a left join, although the OP should use ANSI 92 style syntax anyway

Comment: I cannt use inner join I need all id belong to Table1

Comment: what is ANSI92 style?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.PRICE, t2.IND, t2.CD
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ff55/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ ID   ║ NAME  ║ PRICE  ║  IND    ║   CD   ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ 123  ║ KING  ║ 12.23  ║ 1       ║ A      ║
║ 234  ║ KONG  ║ 23.43  ║ (null)  ║ (null) ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: this is *= left join too. Let me explain my issue... If we look up the description of table2... Name of column: IND Data type: bit Null: No Default Value: 0  So, when this table gets left join with any table its giving us no null and default value as 0.

Comment: hi, iad2025  you solution doesn't work... please lookup again I explain my issue above..

Comment: @Qasim0787 Select does not interfere with `NOT NULL` property. Do you need to insert this data? Your question is very unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the result of your query is how `LEFT JOIN` (or 20 year old syntax `*=`) works.

If there is a row in `t1` with some `ID` and `t2` doesn't have a row with the same `ID`, then

```
t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

would return this row from `t1` and `NULL` values for `t2` columns, because there are no corresponding values in `t2`.

Does Sybase have a `CASE` statement?
Most likely it has. You can use it to replace such `NULL` values with `0`, or whatever you need.

```
select 
    t1.*
    ,CASE WHEN t2.IND IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.IND END AS IND
    ,t2.CD
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where  t1.ID *= t2.ID
```

Comment: Number (515) Severity (16) State (3) Server (ACUST02DS2) Attempt to insert NULL value into column 'Ind', table 'table2'; column does not allow nulls. Update fails.

Comment: Brother in table2 column IND has datatype as BIT which is null not allowed and has default value set as 0.

Comment: 1. Your question is very unclear, I just was guessing what you need. 2. Your question never mentions `INSERT`, so where does the error message about `INSERT` come from? 3. The fact that column `t2.ind` is declared as `NOT NULL` doesn't affect how `LEFT JOIN` works. Result of `LEFT JOIN` can contain `NULL`. It is by design.